# Change Google Chart Data and Appearance with button

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am creating a project that requires being able to display multiple google donut charts with different values and colors for each chart.  Currently, I am creating 3 charts that are navigated to with three buttons on separate html pages with the example google chart code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Work',     11],
              ['Sleep',    7]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'My Daily Activities',
              pieHole: 0.95,
              slices: {
                  0: { color: 'yellow' },
                  1: { color: 'transparent' }
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

But providing different data in the `data` array and different colors in the `slices` array.

Instead of having to create three separate charts with three separate html pages, is there a way to only use 1 chart and change the data and color of the one chart to three different sets of values by just using buttons and 1 html page?  Ideally the solution would have multiple buttons that when clicked, would change the chart to include different sets of data and a different color chart to distinguish the different sets of data but I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this might help you...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
    var dataSales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales'],
      ['2015',  1000],
      ['2016',  1030]
    ]);

    var dataExpenses = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Expenses'],
      ['2015', 600],
      ['2016', 540]
    ]);

    var dataRevenue = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Revenue'],
      ['2015', 400],
      ['2016', 490]
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: 'none',
      title: 'Results',
      pieHole: 0.3,
      slices: {
        0: { color: 'yellow' },
        1: { color: 'transparent' }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataSales, options);

    document.getElementById('sales').addEventListener('click', function () {
      options.slices[0].color = 'yellow';
      chart.draw(dataSales, options);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('expenses').addEventListener('click', function () {
      options.slices[0].color = 'cyan';
      chart.draw(dataExpenses, options);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById('revenue').addEventListener('click', function () {
      options.slices[0].color = 'magenta';
      chart.draw(dataRevenue, options);
    }, false);
  },
  'packages':['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="sales" value="Sales" />
<input type="button" id="expenses" value="Expenses" />
<input type="button" id="revenue" value="Revenue" />

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: What if you wanted to change from piechart to a line chart for only one of the 3?